# Nan row values shifted while using read clipboard in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In my excel I have a data like this:

```
   year quarter
   2017      Q1
   2018      Q2
   2019      Q3
             Q4
```

When I use `read_clipboard` to copy it and get a data frame, I get this:

```
   year quarter
0  2017      Q1
1  2018      Q2
2  2019      Q3
3    Q4    None
```

We can see in the forth row, the `quarter` value is shifted when `year`'s row value is `NaN`.

Any ideas why this happened and how to fixed it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `sep`

```
pd.read_clipboard(sep='/s+')
   year quarter
0  2017      Q1
1  2018      Q2
2  2019      Q3
3            Q4
```